# TypeLoadException on System.Xml.Linq.XDocument when running T4 template on build server

Tags: .net, t4, typeloadexception

I'm having a problem running a T4 template using TextTransform.exe on my build server. On my dev machine the template works perfectly. The error message is as follows.

> error : Running transformation: System.TypeLoadException: Could not instantiate type System.Xml.Linq.XDocument

The build server has the windows 2008 SDK on it, my machine has VS 2008. I thought mayve it couldn't find System.Data.Xml so I ensure the dll was present in the same directory, but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your server may not have .NET 3.5 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I installed .NET 3.5 SP1 and it corrected the problem